# nivo slider catching link title for controlnav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nivo-slider

Basically, in nivoslider, in the js file it is set up so numbers are displayed in the controlnav section. These numbers seem to be gotten from the "rel" info within the code here. I'm just wondering is there anything I can add to this so it retrieves the "title" or "alt" from the link I put into the slideshow. This would mean I could display text that would  in the controlnav that id have control over.

```
 if(settings.controlNav){
        vars.controlNavEl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
        slider.after(vars.controlNavEl);
        for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
            if(settings.controlNavThumbs){
                vars.controlNavEl.addClass('nivo-thumbs-enabled');
                var child = kids.eq(i);
                if(!child.is('img')){
                    child = child.find('img:first');
                }
                if(child.attr('data-thumb')) vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'"><img src="'+ child.attr('data-thumb') +'" alt="" /></a>');
            } else {
                vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
            }
        }
```

I've seen other links where there is talk of replacing `i + 1` with `child.attr("alt)` etc, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem:

Add the line `var child = kids.eq(i);`

Before:

```
vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ child.attr('alt') +'</a>');
```